# Scheme logic reversal

Tags: scheme, boolean, logic, operator-keyword

I'm new to SCHEME, just starting.

I have the following statement inside a  (cond statement

```
((number? (list-ref inputList 0)) (display "First element is not a number"))
```

My problem is that I need it to return FALSE if the statement is true, how do I reverse the logic?

for example in Java it'd be (!(a==b)) or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `not` function:

```
((not (number? (list-ref inputList 0))) (display "First element is not a number"))
```